# Аргументы int argc, char* argv[]

Tags: c++

```
void main (int argc, char* argv[])  {    
FILE *inf, *outf;  
if (argv[1][0] == 'e'){  
    inf = fopen (argv[2], "rb");  
    outf = fopen (argv[3], "wb");  
    DataFile.SetFile (inf);  
    CompressedFile.SetFile (outf);  
    encode ();  
    fclose (inf);  
    fclose (outf);  
    } 
    else if (argv[1][0] == 'd'){  
    inf = fopen (argv[2], "rb");  
    outf = fopen (argv[3], "wb");  
    CompressedFile.SetFile (inf);  
    DataFile.SetFile (outf);  
    decode ();  
    fclose (inf);  
    fclose (outf);  
    }  
}
```

Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, как пользоваться этой программой через командную строку.

Answer (score 2):

```
int argc, char* argv[]
```

`argc` - количество аргументов,
`argv` - массив строк-аргументов

Запуская программу из командной строки, вы пишете:

в windows: `program.exe`

в linux: `./program`

Здесь `program.exe` или `program` есть первый аргумент командной строки (argv[0]), то есть это всегда имя запускаемой программы. Всё, что вы пишете далее через пробел - остальные аргументы.
В программе вы можете их использовать, как вам необходимо.

Comment: а как мне закодировать файл,что мне еще нужно набрать в командной строке помимо названия программы?

Comment: выше же написали:

для кодирования:

    program e source_filename dest_encoded_filename

для декодирования:

    program d source_encoded_filename dest_source_filename

Comment: То есть мне нужно так написать: program e "en.bin" "dec.bin", я правильно поняла?

Comment: опция e означает encode, то есть закодировать. выбирая опцию e вы должны написать сперва имя файла с данными, а затем имя нового файла(будет создан) - закодированного.
опция e означает decode, то есть раскодировать. выбирая опцию d вы должны написать сперва имя закодированного файла, а затем имя нового файла(будет создан), раскодированного.

Comment: Имя файла написать нужно в кавычках или просто имя.расширение?

Comment: Неужели нельзя попробовать оба способа и проверить результат?

Comment: я уже все результаты попробовала не работает ни так,ни так

Comment: Что именно не работает? Какую ошибку говорит или что происходит?

Answer (score 1):

```
program <option> <input file> <output file>

options:
e - encode
d - decode
```